# Use excel to concatenate data in three columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with three colums:

name |
age |
notes

I need to create a colum that has the data of these three colums concatenated with an underscore in between.

For example:

john |
89 |
Handsome |

should look like

john_89_handsome.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

This formula allows you to concatenate the values in the form you would like:

```
= A1 & "_" & B1 & "_" & C1
```